# Release app during holiday shutdown

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

Two hours ago, Apple tells me that "The status for the following app has changed to Pending Developer Release", but I cannot log in to iTunes Connect because "iTunes Connect is unavailable until December 28".

Is there any other way to release the app during the app store holiday shutdown?

Comment: that is a back luck... you need to wait until the _iTunes Connect_ portal is open again.

Comment: It holiday time have fun and let the apple guys celebrate too you will have to wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the portal until the 28th which makes this impossible.  Not sure if apps already set to autorelease on a certain day will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Submission Process FAQ:

> What iTunes Connect, Application Loader, and Transporter features are unavailable during the holiday closure?
> From December 22 to December 29, 2015, the following features will be unavailable:
>
> App submissions for new apps and app updates
>
> App bundle submissions for new bundles and bundles updates
>
> In-App Purchase submissions
>
> TestFlight submissions for external testing
>
> All other features, and access to iTunes Connect, will still work.

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process#68611491